# What does the VS setting: “Follow project coding conventions” do?

Tags: visual-studio, settings, text-editor

`Tools / Options` in Visual Studio "15" Preview 5 
has a setting under `Text Editor / General`
that says `Follow project coding conventions`

I wonder if this means that it is ready for project based coding conventions or not. And if it is, how is it specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio "15" now supports [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/). There is a short preview of it in [The Future of Visual Studio "15"](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-Live-Redmond-2016/W15) talk at 1h 3m.